# How to name the same entity in XML, REST and Database?

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have an entity that has slightly different fields in different tiers of the application. One entity is the data object the receives content from an `XML API`, one for persisting parts of that in a `database`, and one for offering parts of the xml object via a `REST` service:

```
XML API: MyEntityXML
REST: MyEntityDTO
DB: MyEntityDomain
```

How would you name these different entities? Would you just give every Entity the same name (and place them in different packages)?
Or would you give explicit names like,  `*DTO`, `*Domain`, `*XML` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the classes sharing the same name into different packages would not be a good approach because eventually it will create confusion while writing code.

So I will suggest creating class with different name for the same entity depending upon where we are using it.

For Example : User Entity

API  : UserApiDto or UserXmlDto or UserJsonDto

Rest : UserDto

DB   : UserDomainDto

And moreover its depends upon the project structure, it is single module based or multi module based.